# проблема с выводом результата метода

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, методы, вывод

мне надо написать класс Armor() и его наследник GostInArmor().если что, в задании было сказано, что будет передаваться произвольное кол-во кортежей(в том числе ни одного)-это имя лат и их кол-во, а также передают имя рыцаря(имя по умолчанию(если не укажут)-Canterville).выводить нужно отсортированные картежи по алфавиту имён лат(с этим я справился).короче, нужно чтобы мне выводил правильно, а как это сделать-я не знаю((((

```
class Armor():
    def __init__(self, *kortez, name = "Canterville"):
        self.name = name
        self.ll = list(kortez)

class GhostInArmor(Armor):
    def __repr__(self):
        self.ll.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0]))
        return f'GhostInArmor{tuple(self.ll), self.name}'

gia = GhostInArmor(("knee pad", 2), ("handlebar", 1), ("shoe", 1), name="Ghost")
print(gia)
```

Должен выводить

```
GhostInArmor(('handlebar', 1), ('knee pad', 2), ('shoe', 1), name='Ghost')
```

а выводит

```
GhostInArmor((('handlebar', 1), ('knee pad', 2), ('shoe', 1)), 'Ghost')
```

как это можно исправить?
не знаю даже как задать этот вопрос в интернете, поэтому, после долгих попыток найти что-то в интернете, решил задать вопрос сюда. помогите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен))

Comment: для начала вы определитесь: GhostInArmor или GostInArmor

Comment: )
извиняюсь, писал название классов вручную, а при вызове класса взял и скопировал, не заметил))
правильно будет GhostInArmor

Comment: `return f'GhostInArmor({tuple(self.ll)}, name={self.name})'`

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)
это то, что мне нужно было

Comment: ваш код вывел так: 
**`GhostInArmor((('handlebar', 1), ('knee pad', 2), ('shoe', 1)), name=Ghost)`**
@insolor я сделал так:
**`self.name = 'name=' + name`**
**`return f"GhostInArmor{*self.ll, self.name}`**
у меня вывелось: **GhostInArmor(('handlebar', 1), ('knee pad', 2), ('shoe', 1), 'name=Ghost')** 
но надо: **GhostInArmor(('handlebar', 1), ('knee pad', 2), ('shoe', 1), name='Ghost')** 
различие:  **'name=Ghost'** \  **name='Ghost'** как добиться 2 варианта?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Armor():
    def __init__(self, *kortez, name = "Canterville"):
        self.name = name
        self.ll = list(kortez)


class GhostInArmor(Armor):
    def __repr__(self):
        self.ll.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0]))
        return f'GhostInArmor({tuple(self.ll)}, name={self.name!r})'


gia = GhostInArmor((("knee pad", 2), ("handlebar", 1), ("shoe", 1), name="Ghost")
print(gia)
```

Результат:

```
GhostInArmor((('handlebar', 1), ('knee pad', 2), ('shoe', 1)), name='Ghost')
```

Смысл в том, что не все вставляем в одни фигурные скобки внутри f-строки, а отдельные фигурные скобки добавить для name. Для name нужно добавить `!r`, чтобы выводилось repr-представление строки (в кавычках). Ну и общие скобки в строке добавить.

Для примера, разница str-представления и repr-представления:

```
name = "Ghost"
print(str(name))  # Выведет Ghost
print(repr(name))  # Выведет 'Ghost'
```

То же самое на f-строках, обычные фигурные скобки "без параметров" вызывают `str` для преобразования объекта в строку, фигурные скобки с `!r` - `repr`:

```
name = "Ghost"
print(f"{name}")  # Выведет Ghost
print(f"{name!r}")  # Выведет 'Ghost'
```

Для `tuple` это не обязательно делать, т.к. у `tuple` `str` и `repr` представления совпадают.

В целом `repr` используется для отображения объекта в виде "для программиста" - в идеале текст такого представления должен быть корректным кодом на Python. Обычное строковое представление - для пользователя.